# C# Creating MultiDimensional Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm new on c# and i'm trying to make a c# program but i have a problem with arrays.
I used php but i'm converting to c# how can i make something like this

```
$Infos = array("id" => array(), "name" => array(), "age" => array(), "number" => array(), "time" => array(), "version" => array());
```

if any1 can help or show me one example how to do that "multidimensional"(don't know the real name) arrays

Comment: You should search on the net, there are plenty resources available about multidimensional arrays in c#

Comment: Have you at least read a book or article covering the very basics of C# and .NET?

Comment: There are thousands of resources for such a basic concept https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+multidimensional+arrays&aq=f&oq=C%23+multidimensional+arrays&aqs=chrome.0.57j58j60j62l2.5940j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
 class TestArraysClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Declare a single-dimensional array  
        int[] array1 = new int[5];

        // Declare and set array element values 
        int[] array2 = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };

        // Alternative syntax 
        int[] array3 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

        // Declare a two dimensional array 
        int[,] multiDimensionalArray1 = new int[2, 3];

        // Declare and set array element values 
        int[,] multiDimensionalArray2 = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };

        // Declare a jagged array 
        int[][] jaggedArray = new int[6][];

        // Set the values of the first array in the jagged array structure
        jaggedArray[0] = new int[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    }
}
```